# How to pass child output to app component containing router-outlet in Angular

Tags: angular, data-binding, parent-child, eventemitter, angular-event-emitter

I wanna emit a value from a sub component up to the app component. The component structure is like this:

index.html:

```
<app-root></app-root>
```

app.component.html:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

app.component.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  ...
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  change = false;

  ...

  getStatus(value: boolean): void {
    this.change = value;
  }

...
}
```

child.component.ts (gets rendered via the router outlet e.g. from URL like /child):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  ...
})

export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output() doStuff: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  ...

  emitStuff(): void {
    this.doStuff.emit(true);
  }
}
```

child.component.html:

```
<a (click)="emitStuff()">Click</a>
```

Now, where should I attach the `(doStuff)="getStatus()` binding?

Normally in the `<app-child (doStuff)="getStatus()">`, but this is not available like e.g. in a static app.component.html where somewhere the `<app-child></app-child>` selector is written. I just don't get it, sorry ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the parent component, you can retrieve the instance of the current component with:

```
<router-outlet (activate)="onActivate($event)" (deactivate)="onDeactivate()"></router-outlet>
```

Then subscribe to the child's `EventEmitter` which is nothing more than an `Observable`:

```
onActivate(component) {
    if(component instanceof ChildComponent) {
        this.doStuffSubscription = component.doStuff.subscribe(x => ...);
    } 
}

onDeactivate() {
    if(this.doStuffSubscription)
        this.doStuffSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```